# Trying to setup a node.js script as a system service

Tags: node.js, systemd

I am trying to setup a node.js based telegram bot to run as a system service but get **Access Denied** error every time I try to execute it.

Here is the `.service` file I have created.

```
[Unit]
Description=Sonarr Telegram Bot

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/node /home/pi/telegram-sonarr-bot/sonarr.js
Restart=always
User=pi
# Note RHEL/Fedora uses 'nobody', Debian/Ubuntu uses 'nogroup'
Group=nobody
Environment=PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin
Environment=NODE_ENV=production
WorkingDirectory=/home/pi/telegram-sonarr-bot/

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I have tried to run it as user `root` as well but this also doesn't work.
If I execute the node.js file within terminal it works fine fyi.

**Edit: Added /var/log/auth.log file**

```
Apr 17 00:11:16 raspberrypi sudo:       pi : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/var/log ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/nano /etc/systemd/system/sonarrbot.service
Apr 17 00:11:16 raspberrypi sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by pi(uid=0)
Apr 17 00:11:21 raspberrypi sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Apr 17 00:11:23 raspberrypi dbus[339]: [system] Rejected send message, 2 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.10" (uid=1000 pid=9757 comm="systemctl start sonarrbot ") interface="org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager" member="StartUnit" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="org.freedesktop.systemd1" (uid=0 pid=1 comm="/sbin/init ")
Apr 17 00:11:25 raspberrypi sudo:       pi : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/var/log ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/nano /etc/systemd/system/sonarrbot.service
Apr 17 00:11:25 raspberrypi sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by pi(uid=0)
Apr 17 00:11:29 raspberrypi sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
```

Second update:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ systemctl status sonarrbot.service
    ● sonarrbot.service - Sonarr Telegram Bot
       Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/sonarrbot.service; disabled)
       Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Tue 2018-04-17 00:59:39 UTC; 22h ago
      Process: 9804 ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/node /home/pi/telegram-sonarr-bot/sonarr.js (code=exited, status=216/GROUP)
     Main PID: 9804 (code=exited, status=216/GROUP)


pi@raspberrypi:~ $ journalctl -b
No journal files were found.
```

Comment: How do you run `/etc/systemd/system/sonarrbot.service` as root? What is the output from `systemctl status sonarrbot.service`? Are there some hints in `journalctl -b`?

Comment: Updated my original post

Comment: Running service as root doesn't work for me, e.g. `sudo cron.service` gives me `sudo: cron.service: command not found`. Your service is simply disabled. Enable it with `sudo systemctl enable sonarrbot.service` and start it with `sudo systemctl start sonarrbot.service`. What's the status then? What gives you `sudo journalctl -b`? For better troubleshooting on `systemd` you should enable persistent logging in journald. Look at `zcat /usr/share/doc/systemd/README.Debian.gz | less`.

Comment: When running `systemctl enable sonarr.service` I still get the same error "Failed to execute operation: Access denied"

Comment: What operating system you are running? I assume it is `Raspbian`.

Comment: You have to use `sudo` to enable services! Where do you get the error message? On the command line? In a log file? What log file?

Comment: Not sure whats happened but when I enabled it with `sudo` prefixed it worked. However I wanted to test if the service ran on reboot and it didnt, running `sudo systemctl enable (or start) sonarrbot.service` returns nothing back to the terminal. Running the status command simply says "sonarrbot.service start request repeated too quickly, ...rt.; Failed to start Sonarr Telegram Bot."

Comment: I try to understand what you are doing. I ask you but get only partial answers. How to start a service as root? It always start als root under control of `systemd`. What's about `journalctl`? What operating system you are running? Where do you get the error message? I give up.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a variation of the FAQ [Why do things work differently under systemd?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/339645/20239).

Relative binary work in the shell, but [as documented in `man systemd.service`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#ExecStart=), the first argument to `ExecStart=` must be an absolute path to a binary.

Comment: I have included the absolute path (please see updated post), but I still receive the same error.

Comment: When testing, use `sudo` with `systemctl`.  Also, make sure your use `systemctl enable your-app-name` to make it start at boot.

Comment: Running with sudo doesn’t return any errors, but the application definitely isn’t running.